# Failed installing firmata-party globally with npm on Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, firmata

I've run the following command to install the library but I get always several errors which I'm trying to solve.

*npm install -g firmata-party*

i always get errors and the package doesn't get installed. I've even uninstalled nodes.js and npm but the problem is still there.

Any help with this? :(

```
8 warnings and 13 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/serialport/src/serialport.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/matteo/.nvm/versions/node/v13.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/matteo/.nvm/versions/node/v13.0.1/bin/node" "/Users/matteo/.nvm/versions/node/v13.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/matteo/.nvm/versions/node/v13.0.1/lib/node_modules/firmata-party/node_modules/serialport
gyp ERR! node -v v13.0.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! serialport@6.2.2 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the serialport@6.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/matteo/.npm/_logs/2019-11-15T20_54_43_309Z-debug.log
```

Comment: you've snipped quite a few errors from the make that would help diagnosing the issue

Comment: the build is failing at serialport v6.22 which defines special instructions for installing on mac osx here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport/v/6.2.2#mac-os-x

Comment: I try to install the serialport package but it's giving me warnings and then when I try to install again firmata-party the error is still there. How do I solve all those errors?

Comment: please inspect the instructions for installing serialport v6.2.2 at the link above and ensure you have the stated xcode tools and g++ version >= 4.8

Comment: installing serialport separately is likely not an effective solution because firmata-party is requesting a specific version v6.2.2

Comment: I've found that version but how do I install it now? If I run the command from the page you sent me, only the latest package will be installed

Here's the page: https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/releases/tag/v6.2.2

Comment: I've solved the problem by installing an older version of npm, that was the issue :)